# PHP Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php

```
function drupal_build_css_cache($css) {
  $data = '';
  $uri = '';
  $map = variable_get('drupal_css_cache_files', array());
  // Create a new array so that only the file names are used to create the hash.
  // This prevents new aggregates from being created unnecessarily.
  $css_data = array();
  foreach ($css as $css_file) {
    $css_data[] = $css_file['data'];
  }
```

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: data on line 3606.
Line 3606 being: $css_data[] = $css_file['data'];

Comment: Notice: Undefined index can be ignored , and if you don't want to ignore split $css_file in foreach($css as $css_file_var => $css_file_value).

Comment: First, I would like to know what is problem and what do you expet? Second, please read this [Notice undefined index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12770836#12770836) if you want to get rid of the error.

Comment: You might want to print_r $css_file to see the indexes that are available within the array

Comment: @NirpendraPatel you should not just ignore notices. They may not crash your code directly, but most likely lead to some errors. In this case `$css_file['data']` seems to not exist, so you should check for the key and react to the result.

Comment: No, you must not ignore it. It's an indication that your input is not as expected, which means you may need additional validation of that input, or at least a check like `if (isset($css_file['data'])) $css_data[] = $css_file['data'];`

Answer (score 3):

To avoid this error just test if the table fields was initialized with isset () .

```
// Before using $css_file['data'];
if (isset($css_file['data']))
{
    $css_data[] = $css_file['data'];   
}
```

Comment: Thanks..its fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

It is just notice, that you have undefined index; you should first check if is it set:

```
if (isset($css_file['data'])) {
  $css_data[] = $css_file['data'];   
}
```

Otherwise you can turn off notice reporting (put this line at the beginning of your code):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP notice is telling you that `$css_file` has no key `data`. Check what you receive in `$css` variable.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should show what you've tried to fix the issue. As the error shows, it's caused because $css_file['data'] is undefined. You haven't shown us where `$css_file` is defined. `$css_file['data']` is most likely not being defined.